# Rounded corners on Text with background for TextSpriteModel

Tags: ios, swift, photoeditorsdk

On the Text Sprites I'm trying to get rounded corners for the `TextSpriteModel`. I can see that I can have the corners rounded for `TextSpriteView`s as they have their layer properties exposed. It's not the same for `TextSpriteModels`. So while editing I can show the users the corners rounded but I can't find a way to generate a final image with rounded corners for the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately adding rounded corners to the renderer is not supported and also not on our roadmap currently.